# What is the best way to connect on data lake through net sdk using user authentication

Tags: .net, azure, azure-data-lake

I want to append local file to a file on data lake. Can someone post me an example what is the best way to connect on data lake store with .net sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want to login silent without sign in form this is solution:

```
    string _username = <your azure username>
    string _pass = <your azure  password>
    string _adlsAccountName = <name of your data lake store>
    string _subId = <your subscription id>
    string localFolderPath = @"<yourfolderpath>"
    string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localFolderPath, "<yourFile>");
    string remoteFolderPath = "/path on data lake/";
    string remoteFilePath = Path.Combine(remoteFolderPath, "yourFileonDataLake");

var tenantId = "<your tenant id>"; //you can find this in right top corner on azure portal
var nativeClientApp_clientId = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"; // you can use this one
var activeDirectoryClientSettings = ActiveDirectoryClientSettings.UsePromptOnly(nativeClientApp_clientId, new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"));
var creds = UserTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(nativeClientApp_clientId, tenantId, _username, _password).Result;
_adlsClient = new DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient(creds) { SubscriptionId = _subId };
_adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);
```

if u want to have form for log in on data lake just use LoginWithPromptAsyncMethod from UserTokenProvider.

This is setup. Now u can use Upload,Append, etc with _adlsFileSystemClient. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is illustrated at this GitHub repo: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/data-lake-analytics-dotnet-auth-options/

There are a few basic steps:
- collect the information you need to authenticate - clientids, token audiences, tenantid, etc.
- Using that information get a credential. The function GetCreds_User_Popup in that repo contains the code you need for interactive end-user authentication
- and finally, using the creds, create the .NET client objects you need